# How to create forms with React and Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

With Rails I create forms using the form_for tag.

Rails generates the HTML form automatically, including the authenticity_token for security against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

With React I use JSX, so I cannot render erb in a React component.

In a React component I write HTML manually.

I want to use React in my Rails app, and still have the advantages of Rails.

**Or**, if there is no way to get the Rails advantages of form_for when using React as V of my app, how can I write a proper form as a React component?

If I first write my form_for and then look at the rendered HTML, copy it, and paste into my React component, is that a good idea?

For example here is rendered HTML from form_for:

```html
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1AXH9blzaH4qEAAWTvu6aAH84btA/9DZCpFDBhiJ0/H9uAKsPAB/rFQWY1VmWA1yNtFaigO50p6joa3X8CItBA==" />
  

  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_Имя">Имя</label><br>
    <input placeholder="Бил Гейтс" type="text" name="user[name]" id="user_name" />
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Открыть заявку" class="button tiny" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You can't really get the best of both as fas as I'm aware. 

If you use `form_for` you get all the advantages of Rails but React won't know about the DOM of the form so it won't be able to do its thing.

Comment: The big question is: What are you trying to do in your form that you'd want to use React?

Comment: You might be able to utilize the LinkState React mixin. It allows you to bind form inputs to the state of your component. From there, you could handle the submission back to Rails (via API). https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-valuelink

Comment: we should develop rails helpers that generate jsx components : form_for_jsx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can paste `authenticity_token` into react component.

Using `gem react-rails`

```
= react_component 'Form', authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token
```

`form_authenticity_token` is the rails helper.

So you can paste it into your form.

```
<form role='form' accept-charset="UTF-8" action='/action' method='post'>
  ...
  <input type='hidden' name='authenticity_token' value={this.props.authenticity_token} />
  ...
</form>
```

It's not the best solution. I would be happy if someone will tell a better solution.

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

and put the `csrf-token` into a meta tag inside your view/layout if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 8):

If you render the base HTML with Rails and embed a React component to it with `react-rails`, you can write like this:

```
var YourForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var csrfToken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    return (
      <form action='/users' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='patch' />
        <input type='hidden' name='utf8' value='✓' />
        <input type='hidden' name='authenticity_token' value={csrfToken} />
        ...
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render your form inside an invisible block and then clone it into a react component

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/users.scss */
.invisible-form-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```
# app/views/users/edit.html.haml
.invisible-form-container
  = render 'form'
.react-container
```

```coffee
# app/assets/javascripts/components/form.js.jsx.coffee
class @Form extends React.Component
  html_form: ->
    {__html: $('.invisible-form-container').html()}
  render: ->
    `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.html_form()} />`
```

```coffee
# app/assets/javascripts/initializer.coffee
$ ->
  ReactDOM.render(
    `<Form />`,
    $('.react-container')[0]
  )
```

Hope this helps.